# Change background button when pressed it in listview (android)

Tags: android, listview, button

i want to just one icon pressed in all list view ,, when click icon back all icons in all rows purple and make just the newest pressed icon grey ..

[now when i pressed any icon in first row changed and 
the pressed icon in second row not return inactive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44ygR.png)

```
Icon1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("clicled", String.valueOf(position));
                Icon1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1_active);
                Icon2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2_unactive);}});



  Icon2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Icon1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1_unactive);
                Icon2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2_active);});
```

Comment: 1. I don't understand what you want to do and what's wrong. 2. You didn't posted a code.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov edited now with code .. i want to change just one icon and when click another back all button purple and make just the newest pressed icon grey